# Elegant, inter-thread, asynchronous request/response implementation for Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

As the title says, I'm looking for an elegant way of implementing a generic, asynchronous request/response mechanism between threads in Android.

I need to be able to:

- Asynchronously send a request to another object with different types of arguments
- Have that object optionally asynchronously respond by posting a
  response to the sender's queue

Lets say I have objects of type Manager who extend Thread. Each such Manager has a Handler and a Looper, so that they can each asynchronously shove messages to each other's queue.

Simplistically and in pseudo-code, I would implement this as something like this:

```
Manager extends Thread
{
    // loop forever, pulling a request from the queue and handling it
    listenToRequests()
    {
        Looper.prepare()
        m_handler = new Handler()
        {
            handleMessage(msg)
            {
                switch(msg.what)
                {
                    case REQUEST_TYPE_0:
                        handleRequestType0(msg.object, msg.args);
                        break;

                    case REQUEST_TYPE_1:
                        handleRequestType1(msg.object, msg.args);
                        break;

                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Other managers instances would need to allocate a message, populate it and send it to the target manager:

```
msg = targetManager.getHandler().obtainMessage();
    msg.what = REQUEST_TYPE_0;
    msg.object = this;
    msg.args = ...;

msg.sendToTarget();
```

The target manager could then obtainMessage() on the sender, populate a response message and send it.

The problem with the above code is that, while it does tick both requirements, there is a lot of annoying boilerplate code to implement for each message:

- Define a message type in some enumeration (e.g. REQUEST_TYPE_N)
- The population of arguments into a message in order to marshall them
- Add a switch case to dispatch the message and handle it

Using a Runnable does solve the issue of packing in the arguments and eliminating the message dispatching (via switch/case):

```
public void doRequest0(args)
{
    handler.post(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            // do stuff with args...

            args.sender.request0Response(...);
        }
     });
}
```

The problem with this is that, in lieu of callbacks, I would have to declare and implement interfaces for responses. In each such interface function I would have to decorate with the handler.post(new Runnable() ... which also seems like a lot of boilerplate code.

Are there any other options I am missing? It seems like my requirements are humble but my solutions are overly complex syntactically.

Comment: I'm still trying to determine why you want "way of implementing a generic, asynchronous request/response mechanism between threads". If you could describe a bit about the business scenario, it may give us a better understanding of your actual needs and we can make better suggestions.

Comment: The only way I have ever found to do what you want is exactly as you describe - a command enumeration in the message and a switch in the receiver.  A private 'sender' field and a 'returnToSender' method queues the processed object back again.  I can only agree that the switch and action functions are a bit 'boilerplatey', but whatever you do, you are going to need the code and so, for a new action, you have to add a function head/tail, another enumeration value and an extra switch case - it's not all that bad :)  Nested procedures, like Pascal, would be nice - encapsulates actions in one func.

Comment: @CommonsWare I essentially have an application with N objects, each running in their own thread and each with their own state machine. The objects communicate asynchronously - post a message to another element (or two) then enter a state indicating waiting for response. Since there are quite a few message types being passed back and forth, I want to keep the boilerplate code down to a minimum.

Comment: @MartinJames In C/C++ one would use a reactor, passing five arguments: the target, the function on the target to call, arguments to pass to the function, the sender, and a completion callback to be called on the sender. This means there is exactly 0 boilerplate code - the reactor does all the magic to call the target.function in the target context and the target can generically post a response to the sender. I'm looking for something like that, but I think there is no such thing :-/